# MAAS, LANDSCAPE and zfsutils-linux on Ubuntu SNAP Store

Tags: snap, maas, zfs, landscape

I saw that LXD and JUJU are available via snap, is there a way to have also MAAS, LANDSCAPE and zfsutils-linux via snap?

Over LXD and JUJU, now we can install also MAAS via snap [Install from a Snap](https://docs.ubuntu.com/maas/2.2/en/installconfig-snap-install), but zfsutils-linux is still missing.